# Retrieving Value from Another Row in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I am attempting to reference a value in another row for a particular column of data in Spotfire.  As an example, I would like to reference the sales month where the quantity of sales of bronze widgets was equal to the number of Gold Widgets. I've included a column below to show the data I need, "Month Where Bronze Sales = Gold Sales"

```all
Sales Month        Cumulative Bronze Widgets             Cumulative Gold Widgets              Month Where Bronze Sales = Gold Sales
   1/1/2017                                     0                                 1                                              2/1/2017
   2/1/2017                                     1                                 2                                              4/1/2017
   3/1/2017                                     1                                 2                                              4/1/2017
   4/1/2017                                     2                                 3                                              5/1/2017
   5/1/2017                                     3                                 3                                              5/1/2017
   6/1/2017                                     4                                 3                                              5/1/2017
```

I need to accomplish this with an expression without using a script or inserting another table. Is this possible? I've tried the following and other "Over" functions without success for "Month Where Bronze Sales = Gold Sales"

```sql
Case When Max([Cumulative Bronze Widgets]) over ([Sales Month])= [Cumulative Gold Widgets] Then Max([Sales Month]) Over ([Cumulative Bronze Widgets]) else NULL End
```

Answer (score 1):

Spotfire supports getting data from another rows through `OVER` formulas. That requires a common value in the SAME COLUMN of the current row and the one where you get the data from.

You need to match values in different columns, so `OVER` won't work for you.

You can try some workarounds:

### 1. Separate column for each `Cumulative Bronze Widgets`

This works if you expect only a few numbers of `Cumulative Bronze Widgets`:

- "Cumulative Bronze Widgets - 1":
  `Min(IF([Cumulative Bronze Widgets]=1,[Sales Month],Null))`
- "Cumulative Bronze Widgets - 2":
  `Min(IF([Cumulative Bronze Widgets]=2,[Sales Month],Null))`
- ...
- "Month Where Bronze Sales = Gold Sales":
  `Case When [Cumulative Gold Widgets] then [Cumulative Bronze Widgets - 1]

  When [Cumulative Gold Widgets] then [Cumulative Bronze Widgets - 1]

  ....

  End`

### 2. Create a new table

- Create a new cross table visualization for Bronze widgets vs sales month
- save this new visualization as a new table
- create a link between old and new tables ([original table].[gold widgets] = [new table].[bronze widgets]
- you can now filter the original table by filtering the new one; unfortunately you can include data from multiple tables in the same visualization.

Comment: Thank you Máté Juhász. I think the new table option may work best in my example. I will try this and let you know the result.